# Is there a way to open an incognito tab as opposed to an incognito window in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I know I can open an incognito window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>? You cannot combine an incognito tab  with the rest of "normal" tabs. Is there a method/extension that allows me to do this?

Comment: @Dominique, that's not really relevant. There are many reasons. In my case, as a web software developer, I'd often like to log into a system as two different users to see and compare the result. Having those tabs in the same window (and even tab group) would be very nice.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is [still no](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/35oqdy/help_is_there_a_way_to_open_a_new_incognito_tab/cr77ylm/).

> It's not possible to have an incognito tab in the same window as non-incognito tabs. During the early days (2006-7) we discussed that possibility, but it led to too many confusing scenarios where people leaked their private data by mistaking tab types, and other problems. So we ended up forcing the two to be in different windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible out-of-the-box.
Maybe this extension can help: [Incognito this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/incognito-this/icnaplnkjfjncegmphmlfpggildllbho)

Comment: I already tried that extension. It does not have the option to do it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Cent Browser, which is Chromium-based, supports that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/513819) and [edit] your answer accordingly.